# using "like" in cakephp to return search results

Tags: sql, cakephp

this is the scenario:

i typed an address in a search box: "Blk 6 lot 34 brgy teniente tiago"

it must return all the "Blk 6 lot 34 brgy teniente tiago" from the  column "address" of a particular table:

say for example the addresses are these:

```
        1   = "Blk 6 lot 34 brgy teniente tiago gma cavite"
        2   = "Blk 6 lot 34 brgy teniente tiago trece martirez cavite"
        3   = "Blk 100 lot 34 brgy teniente tiago gma cavite"
        4   = "Blk 6 lot 34 brgy teniente tiago gma cavite"
        5   = "whatever address it may be"
```

the 1-4 records should be displayed... but the thing is if you did not type the exact address, as in the EXACT ADDRESS, it won't return anything.

i am coding in cakephp and it looks like this:

```
array('UserDetail.address LIKE'=>'%'.$filterparams['address'].'%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have two similar values

Assign the similar word to a varaiable e.g., `keyword`

and try:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
'conditions' => array('Model.column LIKE' => '%keyword%')
));
```

Comment: yeah but the thing is i will type a bunch of characters/series of strings and it has to return the very exact thing i typed so if nothing matched, it wont return anything

Comment: The 'Like' statement is not usually used for exact matches in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. I actually did not store the value of my query into the variable i was trying to challenge in my controller. so here's what i got now:

```
$address = array('UserDetail.address LIKE'=>'%'.$filterparams['address'].'%');
```